# Javascript: Can't verify if innerHTML is set to a specific image - only works for plain text

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm trying to make a game in javascript where you move an image across a board to get to the goal. The gist is the board is a table with images in each cell, and you click *only* the images near the hero-piece to swap them with the hero piece, and thus move it across the board. The table is pretty straight forward:

```
<table width="60%" align="center" border="1">
  <p id="warning"></p>
  <p id="contents"></p>
  <tr>
    <td height="60"><span onclick="doClick(0,0)" id="cell00" />&nbsp;</td>
    <td><span onclick="doClick(0,1)" id="cell01" />&nbsp;</td>
    <td><span onclick="doClick(0,2)" id="cell02" />&nbsp;</td>
    <td><span onclick="doClick(0,3)" id="cell03" />&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="60"><span onclick="doClick(1,0)" id="cell10" />&nbsp;</td>
    <td><span onclick="doClick(1,1)" id="cell11" />&nbsp;</td>
    <td><span onclick="doClick(1,2)" id="cell12" />&nbsp;</td>
    <td><span onclick="doClick(1,3)" id="cell13" />&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="60"><span onclick="doClick(2,0)" id="cell20" />&nbsp;</td>
    <td><span onclick="doClick(2,1)" id="cell21" />&nbsp;</td>
    <td><span onclick="doClick(2,2)" id="cell22" />&nbsp;</td>
    <td><span onclick="doClick(2,3)" id="cell23" />&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="60"><span onclick="doClick(3,0)" id="cell30" />&nbsp;</td>
    <td><span onclick="doClick(3,1)" id="cell31" />&nbsp;</td>
    <td><span onclick="doClick(3,2)" id="cell32" />&nbsp;</td>
    <td><span onclick="doClick(3,3)" id="cell33" />&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

A javascript function will populate the cells with images (the eventual goal is to randomize the board), so it starts off blank.

And here's the relevant javascript

```
function doClick(row, col) // This is what's failing, on the 
// innerHTML checks which aren't registering the hero image presence
{
  var top = row - 1;
  var bottom = row + 1;
  var left = col - 1;
  var right = col + 1;
  swapped = false;
  if (top != -1 && (cells[top][col].innerHTML == "<img src='images/Hero.jpg'/>"))
    swap(cells[row][col], cells[top][col]);
  else if (right != 4 && (cells[row][right].innerHTML == "<img src='images/Hero.jpg'/>"))
    swap(cells[row][col], cells[row][right]);
  else if (bottom != 4 && (cells[bottom][col].innerHTML == "<img src='images/Hero.jpg'/>"))
    swap(cells[row][col], cells[bottom][col]);
  else if (left != -1 && (cells[row][left].innerHTML == "<img src='images/Hero.jpg'/>"))
    swap(cells[row][col], cells[row][left]);
  else {
    document.getElementById("warning").innerHTML = "Failed to move";
    //document.getElementById("contents").innerHTML =     
    //  cells[top][col].innerHTML + 
    //  cells[row][right].innerHTML + 
    //  cells[bottom][col].innerHTML + 
    //  cells[row][left].innerHTML;
  }

  checkWinner();
}


function swap(firstCell, secondCell) // The swap function, that is never reached
{
  swapped = true;
  secondCell.innerHTML = firstCell.innerHTML;
  firstCell.innerHTML = "<img src='images/Hero.jpg'/>";
}
```

The problem here are those checks to see if the clicked on square is near the 'hero' square - It fails every time. The confusing part is if I replace the images with plaintext, like say the hero piece is just an empty space character and the innerhtml checks are only looking for that, then it all works fine. So clearly I'm missing something here for how to do an innerhtml check for an image content.

I did try putting the image code inside a variable so the innerhtml check just looks for that, but that didn't work either. I also tried printing what the program thought was in the surrounding cells, and it did indeed show the images (see the commented out "getElementById("contents")" line in full code below). The only situation that worked was when I replace the hero image with just plain text - it can check for that just fine. But I want this to use images, so, what all am I missing here?

Full code for context: https://pastebin.com/m8f4gRPZ

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your table is invalid. Look - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table

Comment: The rendered HTML you see in "contents" might not match the "innerHTML" propery. To see the property's value, maybe try using `console.log` instead of `getElementById("contents").innerHTML=`. Also, `innerHTML` could be a tricky property to get an exact match for, so maybe match something else (such as, say,  the image's `src` property, with something like: `cells[top][col].querySelector("img").src.toLowerCase() == "images/hero.jpg"`).

Comment: `.innerHTML` will never produce attributes with single quotes — always with double quotes — and it won’t include the `/` of the self-closing tag. `.innerHTML` should not be compared against. Please use the [DOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_DOM_API) properly, as suggested in the previous comment.